# .NET - Retrieving details of all Domain Controllers, regardless of DC connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, active-directory

**Objective:** I need to obtain a list of all domain controllers in a given domain and populate the following details about each (at the minimum):

- DNS Name
- NetBios Name (if available)
- Sid

I need to populate this list to include DCs that are offline/disconnected.

Currently, I use System.DirectoryServices to get the list of domain controllers. I can obtain the DC's DNSName without connecting to the DCs directly, but if I try to use an LDAP request to obtain the other info, there is a long delay (as expected) until the request times out.

The following is a (hopefully temporary) way of getting at least the DNSName of each DC, or more info if the user is willing to exclude offline DCs and wait for their timeouts:

```
public static IEnumerable<AdDomainController> GetDomainControllersForDomain(string domainDnsName, string username, string password, bool waitForConnection = true)
{
    List<AdDomainController> targetList = new List<AdDomainController>();
    try
    {
        var context = ActiveDirectoryHelper.GetDirectoryContext(username, password, domainDnsName);                
        using Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(context);

        if(waitForConnection)
        {
            foreach (DomainController dc in domain.DomainControllers)
            {
                string computerObjectName = dc.GetNonPublicPropertyValueString("ComputerObjectName");
                using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", dc.Name, computerObjectName), username, password))
                {
                    targetList.Add(new AdDomainController()
                    {
                        DnsName = dc.Name,
                        NetBiosName = dirEntry.Properties["name"].Value.ToString(),
                        DomainName = domain.Name,
                        OSVersion = dc.OSVersion,
                        ObjectGuid = dirEntry.Guid.ToString(),
                        ObjectSid = dirEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value != null ? ActiveDirectoryHelper.ConvertSidToString(dirEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value as byte[]) : string.Empty
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DomainController dc in domain.DomainControllers)
            {
                targetList.Add(new AdDomainController()
                {
                    DnsName = dc.Name,
                    DomainName = domain.Name
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.AuditException(e, "Cannot read domain information, skipping this domain: " + domainDnsName);
    }
    return targetList;
}
```

**Can this extra info about a domain controller be obtained without directly connecting to said domain controller?**

Comment: Every domain controller in a domain has the details of every other domain controller. it looks like in your loop you are specifying to connect to the same domain controller as you are querying (3rd argument in directoryentry), but this is not neccessery, simply connect to the first one that responds and then reuse that connection

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is a great point. Would Domain.FindDomainController() have any chance of being hung up trying to reach a DC which is disconnected before trying one that is reachable, or is it smarter than that? I couldn't really tell from the documentation.

Comment: It's been a while since i've used that, but as far as i recall, it was never a noticable delay.